# Retrieve API Gateway deployment endpoints to use them in frontend app

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, github-actions, continuous-deployment

I deploy my service in AWS by using The Serverless Framework.
In my `serverless.yml` file I have defined 4 lambda functions so, 4 endpoints will be created once the deployment is finished. I want to inject these endpoints into my frontend code somehow in an automated way so, I though about creating some aws parameters in the aws parameters store to save the endpoints so they will be available for my frontend code.
Do you think is the correct way of proceeding to achieve this task? In that case, would you define this workflow in the serverless.yml file or otherwise you would create a github action step for this?

Thanks in advance!